# Redirecting a file using a fake folder

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect a file using a fake folder, but I can not get it to work properly. I've been searching and trying different things but none of them worked out for me.

**How my current URL looks like:**
/new-weblog.php

**How I want the URL to look like:**
/weblogs/new-weblog.php

I do not want to redirect ALL urls to have the fake /weblogs/ folder. Only just for that one specific file.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to create a fake folder? why not create it and deny permission for directory indexing...?

Comment: Read this: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: @odedta I dont want plenty of folders in my root for just one single file.

Comment: monkeybread, did the url I provided help? I myself have no idea how to write htaccess commands, I usually just copy snippets online since there doesn't seem to be a good and comprehensive tutorial for that online.

Comment: @odedta I'm currently looking at it and trying it out. I do not know how to write htaccess commands either so I'm just tryin out snippets like you ;p

**EDIT** I've got it working. Thank you! :D

Comment: Sweet as! :) vote up if possible

Comment: @odedta I cant, you havent answered my question, posted a comment instead. Answer my question and I will! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't qualify as an answer, however, this is a good tutorial that will give you the desired solution you're looking for and teach you about htaccess commands while you're at it.

Here's the link: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: Well that link solved my problem, so to me it does quality as an answer. Once again, thank you!